# Escaping double quote in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, escaping, string-interpolation, git-tag

I am trying to create tag in a Jenkinsfile.

I've tried the following combinations:

**Attempt one**

```
sh "git tag -a ${params.Version} -m \"${params.Message}\" ${hash} -f"
```

Result:

```
tag tag -a 1.0.1 -m Unquoted commit message 123456 -f
```

Which obviously won't work

**Attempt two**

```
sh "git tag -a ${params.Version} -m \\"${params.Message}\\" ${hash} -f"
```

Result:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 84: unexpected char: '\' @ line 84, column 81.
   rsion} -m \\"${params.Message}\\" ${hash
```

**Attempt three**

```
sh "git tag -a ${params.Version} -m \\\"${params.Message}\\\" ${hash} -f"
```

Result:

```
git tag -a 1.0.1 -m "Full release pipeline" 4618df91ff80e99cdd16f3849da06234e2385066 -f
fatal: too many params
```

Looks good, but apparently something is wrong.

How do you do this?

**Edit**

This is the only thing I've gotten to work, but it's a pain to read and maintain this.

```
sh 'git tag -af ' + params.Version + ' -m "' + params.Message + '" ' + hash
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sh -c "git tag -a ${params.Version} -m \\\\"${params.Message}\\\\" ${hash} -f"
```

Seems to work.

Comment: What is the `-c` flag in this case? I can't find anything about that in the documentation

Comment: I tried with and without `-c` in the Jenkins pipeline, both fail unfortunately.

Comment: It tells the shell to read the command from its arguments rather than standard input or a file. See `man sh`.

Comment: What is your system `sh`?

Comment: Both the slave that runs the job and the docker container use bash. But keep in mind this in a Jenkinsfile, not in a shell. Jenkins does not know what the `-c` flag is. https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/

Comment: Ah, okay. Have you tried single quoting the message, since the substitution should have already taken place?

Comment: Jenkins doesn't support single quoted strings and interpolation unfortunately, my edit above seems to be the only viable option.